# Where do I go Java EE jar shopping?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jms

I installed Java EE Eclipse and am trying to get at `ServletContextListener` but see that its not available when I try to search for it in my JDK. According to the API docs its located under `javax.servlet` package, but I can't seem to find the JAR anywhere.

Same for a lot of JMS classes. Guess I'm just confused where a Java EE developer is supposed to go for Java EE jars. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did your version of Eclipse come with the EE JDK?

Comment: Your application server is responsible for providing these classes at runtime, so they must be somewhere in its `.jar`s.

Comment: What I do sometimes when my project isn't managed by Maven is to download directly from any Maven artifact repository.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java EE jars are typically part of your web container or EJB implementation; e.g.

- Tomcat,
- Jetty,
- Glassfish,
- JBoss,
- Websphere,
- etcetera.

Note that some of these only support a subset of Java EE technology, and accordingly have a smaller footprint.

The other alternative is to look on the Oracle website (or elsewhere) for a stand-alone implementation.  For instance, Oracle provides a stand-alone JAR file for "javax.mail", which is part of Java EE.

Comment: So how do you develop Java EE apps inside Eclipse (if the JARs are inside the container)?

Comment: @herpylderp You point your Eclipse project at the .jars of the container you're using for development. (And tell Eclipse to not bundle them in your .wars.)

Comment: @herpylderp - or if you are using Maven, you add the relevant dependencies to your POM file with scope "provided".

Answer (score 0):

For a beginner Java EE developer I (and many others before me) recommend not using the IDE and configure everything you need manually (at least once).

If you choose Tomcat what you're looking for is servlet-api.jar.

In brief the steps you would take to develop and use a class that implements ServletContextListener:

1. Download Tomcat (or any of the other servlet containers listed in the other answer).
2. Include Tomcat's servlet-api.jar in the compile classpath.
3. (Optional) Package and deploy to tomcat.